# jquery putting json in a dialog

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, dialog, alert

I have this piece of code inside a `jQuery` focusout :

```
$.ajax({ 
   type : 'GET',
   data : 'auteur='+auteurExiste,
   url  : 'existeAuteur.php',
   success: function(data) {
      jQuery.each(data, function(index,item) {
      alert ("bla bla bla "+item)
      });
    }               
});
```

The `json` response from `existeAuteur.php` is :

> 0:"Le droit privé"
>
> 1:"Le droit foncier"

This of cours opens an alert per item. (logical since the alert is within the jQuery.each).

But how can I put the list of items in one single alert box, or in a single `jQuery.dialog`. I tried to put the `jQuery.each` in a function dialog but without success.

Thanks !

Comment: That's not JSON. An array in JSON looks like `["Le droit privé","Le droit foncier"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DO YOU WANT TO** put the all the item names in one message alert ?

If I understand your question right, then this should work.

```
$.ajax({ 
   type : 'GET',
   data : 'auteur='+auteurExiste,
   url  : 'existeAuteur.php',
   success: function(data) {
      var items = "";

      jQuery.each(data, function(index,item) {
           // Let's say the item[0] = "gum01" and item[1] = "gum02" and so on...
           // Then 'items' will contain "gum01gum02gum03gum04gum05..." in a single row.
           // so you may want to give it line feeds with "\n"
           items += item + "\n"
      });

      alert(items);
    }               
});
```

Try this code.

Comment: Why not just `items = data.join("\n")`?

Comment: @Barmar that I didn't know of. Thank you for suggestion. But is it possible to use `.join()` on Json object directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to write what is currently the alert to a single string, then put that string in an alert after the $.each is resolved? So in the sense of this:

```
var result = "";
$.each(data, function(index,item) {
    result += "bla bla bla "+ item
});
alert(result)
```

Or is that not what you're trying to achieve?